# Inherit from field/method targeted annotation

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, annotations, eclipselink

I'm annotating my classes here and there and I find myself repeating the following:

```
public class Example
{
    @Basic
    @Convert("converter")
    private AnotherExample ae;
}
```

To save me some hassle and to ensure correct usage I came up with the idea to create an annotation that inherits from both `@Basic` and `@Convert("converter")`. The problem is that both annotations have `@Target(value={FIELD, METHOD})` and thus I cannot annotate my custom annotation with them.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal or is this a limitation of Java's annotations?

Comment: Unless AnotherExample is an entity, shouldn't Basic be the default and so not be needed?

Comment: @Chris The annotations are just 'for example'. But if you must know; `AnotherExample` is an enum annotated with `@Converter` and `@Embeddable`. `Example` is annotated with `@Entity`. `@Basic` is needed, else the conversion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is literally the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem) from multiple inheritance.

I would argue against trying to merge these annotations together.  The point of inheritance is not to save typing.  These two annotations are separate for a reason.

Most IDEs can create code from macros which will cut down on your typing.  Otherwise, a search and replace regex would definitely work as well.

Comment: I feel I have to disagree on the diamond problem. Annotations can be combined if `@Target` is set to `ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE`. Multiple annotations can be combined this way. It's not only to save typing, I more want to ensure both annotations are used when using some type.